# Oracle Date Comparison Issue Totally confused - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am newbie & learning Oracle. I want to compare dates in function, while implementing the function I got an issue that output is wrong and not getting a valid answer I search a lot for a solution but in vain....

Solution so far I found was:

1. Do not compare Datetime to date.
2. If using DateTime, first TRUNC is needed to remove time factor.
3. While comparing date first convert dates to To_char(anyDate,'dd-mon-yyyy');
4. if we are comparing date like 1-dec-13 to 27-dec-13, make sure that both of the year are same. like both should be of 2013.

I have passed through all the constraints so far i found but fail to find the solution. Can any body help me. what blunder am i doing? Thanks in advance for anticipation.

```
 SET serveroutput on;
 DECLARE
 startDate DATE := to_date('1'|| '/' ||to_char(sysdate, 'MM')  || '/2013','DD/MM/YYYY'); 
 secDate DATE :=to_date(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY ');

 BEGIN

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'if secDate  '|| secDate ||' is Greater Then'); 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'StartDate '|| startDate || ' Output = ' );   

   if(secDate>startDate)
    then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('True' ); 
    else    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('false'); 

   end if;
end;
```

Comment: `I got an issue` What is the issue?

Comment: What are you expecting that pl/sql block should "print"? `that output is wrong and not getting a valid answer` what is the right output for you? The output most likely is going to be `true`. What do you expect it to be?

Comment: if secDate is > then startDate it should print true isn't it???

Comment: @YOusaFZai Yes it should but now it prints `false`. See my answer why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`to_date(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY ')` that is your problem. It gives `27.12.0013` as a result. That is why you get `false` printed. Actually you don't need to convert `sysdate` to date as it is already of type date. Use this instead:

```
secDate DATE := SYSDATE;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your points in order:

**i** An Oracle `DATE` holds date and time, accurate to the second. You can compare them, for example `12/27/2013 00:00:00` is less than `12/27/2013 09:00:00`.

**ii** If you want to see if two `DATE` values with a time component (for example `12/27/2013 14:00:00` and `12/27/2013 12:34:56`) are on the same day, then yes, you want `TRUNC`: `IF TRUNC(firstDate) = TRUNC(secondDate)`.

**iii** There's nothing to be gained by using `TO_CHAR` for comparing `DATE` values. Use `TRUNC` if you don't want to include the time in the comparison; leave it out if you want the time.

**iv** The years don't have to be the same. A date like `12/27/2013` is greater than `12/27/2012` and less than `12/27/2014`. If you leave it as a `DATE` type Oracle will do the right thing.

As for what's going wrong with your code, take a look at your `startDate` initialization:

```
'1'|| '-' ||to_char(sysdate, 'MM')  || '2013'
```

For today, that will give you `1-122013`, which doesn't match the format string `DD/MM/YYYY` in the `TO_DATE` call. That's why you're not getting a decent date.

If you want to get the first day of the current month, Oracle provides a convenient shortcut:

```
startDate := TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH');
```

So I'd forget about all the formatting and go with something like this; note how it's a lot simpler:

```
SET serveroutput on;
DECLARE
  startDate DATE := TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH');
  secDate DATE := SYSDATE;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'if secDate  '|| secDate ||' is Greater Then'); 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'StartDate '|| startDate || ' Output = ' );   

  if(secDate>startDate) then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('True' ); 
  else    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('false'); 
  end if;
END;
```

Note that `secDate` will be equal to `startDate` only at midnight on the first day of the month, when both values (for December 2013) will be `12/27/2013 00:00:00`. At all other times of the month, `secDate` will be greater.

And note that I used `12/27/2013 00:00:00` to explain December 27, 2013 at midnight. That's just so I could explain the date in English. It's not how Oracle stores dates. How does Oracle store dates? It doesn't really matter - the important thing is that Oracle handles the date just fine if you leave it in `DATE` format and use `TRUNC` when you care only about the date and not about the time.

Comment: Thanx Gibbs your solution is absolutely right but in my question i changed the format and getting the same output just look at the edited question.

Comment: What output are you getting? Something to note about `secDate DATE := to_date(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY ')`: you're calling `to_date` on a value that's *already* a date. That can be tricky because Oracle expects a `char` so it will convert `SYSDATE` to char, and it does that using its default date format. If your default date format isn't `DD/MM/YYYY` then the conversion won't work. To strip the time from a date, *always* use `TRUNC` because it doesn't rely on the date format being a specific value. I just works. Only use `TO_CHAR` for formatting dates, not for manipulating them.

Answer (score 0):

See this line `to_date('1'|| '-' ||to_char(sysdate, 'MM')  || '2013','DD/MM/YYYY');`

`'1'|| '-' ||to_char(sysdate, 'MM')  || '2013'` gives you '1-122013', so you make 
`to_date('1-122013','DD/MM/YYYY');`

The format don't match, you have to change one of them, either

`to_date('01/'|| to_char(sysdate, 'MM')|| '/2013','DD/MM/YYYY');`

or

`to_date('01'|| '-' ||to_char(sysdate, 'MM')|| '2013','DD-MMYYYY')`

Instead of `secDate DATE :=to_date(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY ');` simply use `secDate DATE :=TRUNC(SYSDATE);`, there is no need for a conversion.

Comment: i have edit the question. I already had tried with same format. its not the solution.

Comment: `The format don't match` Not quite correct. When you convert string literal to a value of `date` data type it doesn't matter what character is used as a delimiter. `to_date('01-122013', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` is as valid as `to_date('01.12.2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`  and as valid as `to_date('01/12/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`